# Mysql query- weighted average with group by and max timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the weighted average of the amount for each player by the weight of the amount of the max timestamp for each desk

For example for the following table:

### desk | player | amount | weight | timestamp

---- 1 --- | ---- 1 --- | ---------2------|-----10-------|13:00
---- 1 --- | ---- 1 --- | ---------1------|-----15-------|14:00
---- 2 --- | ---- 1 --- | ---------5------|-----20-------|13:00
---- 2 --- | ---- 1 --- | ---------3------|-----5-------|15:00
---- 3 --- | ---- 2 --- | ---------5------|-----6-------|13:00
---- 3 --- | ---- 2 --- | ---------2------|-----30-------|14:00
---- 4 --- | ---- 2 --- | ---------1------|-----10-------|15:00
---- 4 --- | ---- 2 --- | ---------6------|-----3-------|13:00

the result should be:

**player | weigtedAmount**

---1---| 1.5 ((15/20)*1 + (5/20)*3)

---2---| 1.75 ((30/40)*2 + (10/40)*1)

I tried the following query, but i think that i am missing some timestamp = max(timestamp) somewhere:

```
select player,SUM(lates_data.amount * (lates_data.weight/ lates_data.sumWeight)) from

(SELECT * FROM

(select player as plr, SUM(weight) as sumWeight from playersDb.player_stats group by plr) t1 

INNER JOIN

(select desk,player,amount,weight from playersDb.player_stats group by desk,player) t2

ON t1.plr= t2.player) lates_data
group by player
```

Any idea?

Raz

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that should produce your required results.

```
#DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deskWeight;

CREATE TABLE deskWeight (desk INT UNSIGNED, player INT UNSIGNED, amount INT UNSIGNED, weight INT UNSIGNED, `timestamp` TIME);

INSERT INTO deskWeight VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 10, '13:00'),
    (1, 1, 1, 15, '14:00'),
    (2, 1, 5, 20, '13:00'),
    (2, 1, 3, 5, '15:00'),
    (3, 2, 5, 6, '13:00'),
    (3, 2, 2, 30, '14:00'),
    (4, 2, 1, 10, '15:00'),
    (4, 2, 6, 3, '13:00');

SELECT A.player, SUM(A.weight / B.weightSum * A.amount) weightedAmount FROM 
    (
    SELECT A.player, B.weight, B.amount FROM
        (
        SELECT desk, player, MAX(`timestamp`) timestampMax FROM deskWeight GROUP BY desk, player
        ) A
    INNER JOIN
        deskWeight B
    ON A.desk = B.desk AND A.player = B.player AND A.timestampMax = B.`timestamp`
    ) A
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.player, SUM(B.weight) weightSum FROM
        (
        SELECT desk, player, MAX(`timestamp`) timestampMax FROM deskWeight GROUP BY desk, player
        ) A
    INNER JOIN
        deskWeight B
    ON A.desk = B.desk AND A.player = B.player AND A.timestampMax = B.`timestamp`
    GROUP BY A.player
    ) B
ON A.player = B.player
GROUP BY player;
```

Regards,

James

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!

I managed to do it with this query:

```
SELECT player, sum(aw)/sum(weight) as total, sum(weight) as weight, max(timestamp) as timestamp FROM
    (
        SELECT player, desk, amount*weight as aw, weight, timestamp FROM 
        (
            (SELECT player as p1, desk as d1, max(timestamp) as maxTs FROM playersDb.player_stats group by player, desk) mts
            inner join
            (SELECT * FROM playersDb.player_stats) data
        on data.player = mts.p1 and data.desk = mts.d1 and data.timestamp = mts.maxTs
        )
    ) t
group by player
```

Raz